# Possible symlink attack

Tags: windows, windows-7, pear

Every single time I want to upgrade or install a PEAR package I get the following series of error messages:

> C:>pear upgrade
>   Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: SECURITY ERROR: Will not write to C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache\6d1f6e892384ae452db9a1bd59ee95f5rest.cacheid as it is symlinked to C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache\6d1f6e892384ae452db9a1bd59ee95f5rest.cacheid - Possible symlink attack
>   [...]

What symlink is it talking about? When I copy and paste both paths and put them side by side I honestly can't spot the difference:

```
C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache\6d1f6e892384ae452db9a1bd59ee95f5rest.cacheid
C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache\6d1f6e892384ae452db9a1bd59ee95f5rest.cacheid
```

The error goes away when I empty the cache dir:

```
C:\>pear clear-cache
reading directory C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache
74 cache entries cleared
```

... until the next time I need to install stuff.

My questions are:

1. Why are those errors being triggered?
2. Is there any way to prevent them from showing up in the first place?

**Edit:** There's an [open ticket](https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18834) about this filed on late 2011. The issue was caused by a security fix for [Symlink attack in PEAR install](https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18056). I'll report back with whatever comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a PEAR bug:

- [Bug #18056 regression on windows](https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18834)

The bug was fixed on [PEAR 1.9.5](https://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/download/1.9.5), released on 12th July 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the entire contents of the pear\cache directory in your User directory C:\Users\ALVARO.GONZALEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache\

Then you should be able to do the pear installs

Comment: `pear clear-cache` empties that directory as well. Why do I need to do it manually? What would that solve?

Comment: My apologies, I was reading this too quickly and didn't realize your real question. Thought you just wanted to "make it work" once.  You're right, pear clear-cache does the same thing.

Comment: It's alright, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. So far, my conclusion is that it's a security mechanism gone bad but the PEAR project is quite stall.